# ExecuteScalar "Specified cast is not valid" exception

Tags: c#, exception, executescalar

The following line of code *sometimes* results in "Specified cast is not valid" exception:

```
public static object Select(string sql, OleDbTransaction dbt)
{
  try
  {
     OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, lib.dbc, dbt);
     object obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar(); /* <- this is what fails */
     return obj;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    /* deleted code - error message to the user */
    return null;
  }
}
```

This function is executed several times in the program before it fails. If fails olny when it's executed in a new execution thread, and then only *sometimes*. When I call the part of the program which performs processing in a thread, and it calls this function, either it works all the time (=> I click the button, it executes, no error, I click and execute again and again...), or it never works (=> I click the button and execute, exception, I click and execute again, exception again...).

lib.dbc -> static variable of type OleDbConnection initialized only at program startup and used very often throughout the code, valid

I have no idea how to debug it any further, and above all, what assignment to a variable of type object can fail? ExecuteScalar should return object or null. Database I'm using is Jet (MS Access).

In the exception I find this stack trace, maybe it can help:

```
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.IOpenRowset()
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteTableDirect(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteScalar()
at FK.sql.Select(String sql, OleDbTransaction dbt)
```

Comment: What is the SQL here? Are you *actually* issuing a query resulting in a single value?

Comment: Are you sharing the same connection over multiple threads? ADO.NET isn't designed for that. @JonSkeet `ExecuteScalar` returns "the first column of the first row in the result set, or a null reference if the result set is empty."

Comment: @C.Evenhuis: Good point. The threading thing may well be the issue. It still isn't a great idea to use ExecuteScalar for results with more than one column/row IMO, but it shouldn't give this error.

Comment: SQL is always "select...". What it returns should have no importance, it could result only in logical errors since the function is a wrapper made to manage any SELECT result. Regarding threading, I have a main thread which, for this particular case (long execution) spawns 2 other threads - 1 SQL processing thread and 1 dialogue thread. I found some info that I might need ApartmentState = ApartmentState.MTA for my threads, I don't know much about what this is. At any given moment, just 1 thread does SQL stuff. My function returns one data or null, that's its job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If fails olny when it's executed in a new execution thread, and then only sometimes.

This statement, combined with the fact you're passing in the connection as a parameter, suggests you may be trying to use the same database connection, and maybe transaction, on multiple threads.

Don't: instead create a new connection each time you want to access the database: connection pooling means that this will be efficient.

Comment: Yes, I'm sharing the DB connection, had no idea that in a multi-threaded environment it'd cause such a havoc. When I don't share a connection among the threads I didn't manage to reproduce the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, just as a diagnostic tool:

```
public static object Select(string sql, OleDbTransaction dbt)
{
  try
  {
     using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(lib.dbc.ConnectionString))
     using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con, dbt))
     {
         object obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
         return obj;
     }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    /* deleted code - error message to the user */
    return null;
  }
}
```

This may help determine whether you have a threading problem.